# How to remove files in command line with specific words in the filename?

Tags: webpack, command-line-interface, package.json, yarnpkg

I need to remove all webpack files in assets folder in when I do a clear for local build in package.json

```
 rm ../app/assets/name-bundle.js
 rm ../app/assets/name-bundle-sourcemaps.js
```

The above works fine. However I am wondering if there is a way to do remove all files with `bundle` in the file name

Answer (score 1):

Since it isn't recursive, and everything is in one folder, you can just use wildcards.

First, cd to your folder, then remove files with the string `bundle`:

```
cd ../app/assets
rm *bundle*
```

[Probable duplicate / source.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443830/delete-all-files-whose-filenames-contain-a-particular-string)

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you're in bash. I'd recommend adding a tag specifying exactly what CLI you're using.

Comment: You don't even need to `cd` first. Just use the folder name in the `rm` command `rm ../app/assets/*bundle*`

Comment: Running `rm` is independent of the shell you're using, and even the wildcards used didn't look that fancy that the shell would make a difference. The `bash` or other shell tag is important for scripts with loops and if blocks.